# how to display products from every seller and make it changing every time page reloading?

Tags: django

The default displaying in django is for the latest product first .
how can I change the viewing way ?

my view.py coding

```
@login_required()
def products(request):
    f = ForSaleProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.filter(status=ProductStatus.LISTED).order_by('-pub_date'))
    paginator = Paginator(f.qs, NB_PER_PAGE)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    pproducts = paginator.get_page(page)
    request.session['products_filters'] = request.GET
    return render(request, 'products/products.html', {'filter': f, 'pproducts': pproducts})
    sale = PorductSale()
    sale.product = product
    sale.buyer = buyer
    sale.seller = seller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it resolved by making

```
Product.objects.filter(status=ProductStatus.LISTED).order_by('?')
```

as my project is a small market have vendors and many product I wanted to change the products viewing way where every page be include some products from every vendor so now by changing   `order_by('-pub_date')` to   `order_by('?')` I got a random viewing way and every page included some products from every vendor

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand, you are trying to view `pproducts` with other orders like `name` or `price`.

You've already done that in your code above

All you need to do is change the value inside `order_by` to something like:

```py
Product.objects.filter(status=ProductStatus.LISTED).order_by('name')
```

or by `price`

```py
Product.objects.filter(status=ProductStatus.LISTED).order_by('price')
```

The "-" means the result will be returned in reserved order.

Comment: I want to view by sellers but I don't want to be Sequential order viewing I want to view some product from every seller in every page (mixing the products viewing by seller) especially first page